# Weird behavior of cin and char array

Tags: c++, arrays, types, char, cin

C++ beginner here. I'm trying to make a program to add 2 binary numbers without much success. My idea (I didn't want to see solutions to the exercise yet) was to get input for 2 arrays and then use the positions on the arrays to compare the two with values with a third carry over.

E.g. if last number on the first number is 1 and last number on the second number is 1, then set last number to 1 and carry 1. After that, if second to last number on the first number is 1 and second to last number on number 2 is 0, then set second number to 1 and carry 1. Something like that. Probably with a loop; not sure it will work but I wanted to try it, part of the exercise and all that.

But I didn't even get to the meat of the program because I can't get cin to work properly with the arrays.

See:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char bin1[3]{0,0,0};
    char bin2[3]{0,0,0};
    cin>>bin1;
    cin>>bin2;
    cout<<bin1[0];
    cout<<bin2[0];
}
```

Input:
"123"
"321"
Returns:
" 3"

Why is it not returning 13?

And then:

```
{
    char bin1[3]{0,0,0};
    int n=1;
    int r;

    cin>>bin1;
    r=bin1[n]+bin1[n];
    cout<<r;
}
```

Input:
111
Returns:
98

Why is it not returning 2?

But:

```
{
    char bin1[3]{0,2,0};
    int n=1;
    int r;


//    cin>>bin1;
    r=bin1[n]+bin1[n];
    cout<<r;
}
```

Returns 4 as expected.

When I call every previously initialized position in the array it returns the correct number, and when I do operations with those numbers everything is working as expected; so it's not because I'm mixing char and int... right? I'm pretty sure I tested every possibility, even initialized the arrays with 0 on declaration just to make sure.

It only starts to fall apart when the input from cin is factored in. I tried to use stringstream but I don't think it works with char arrays, not sure?

Honestly I'm at a loss, it's probably some obvious mistake but I combed through the tutorials and can't find the answer.

Comment: You are invoking UB because your character strings are too small for your input. `"123"` is a _four_-character array: `{ '1', '2', '3', '\0' }`

Comment: maybe you can try `string`?

Comment: *I'm pretty sure I tested every possibility* -- `std::string bin1, bin2;` -- Did you try those?  And as mentioned, what if "123456" is entered?  Your program has no way of changing the length of the arrays to fit the data entered.  A more robust program would use `std::string`, get the shorter of the two entered values, and zero-pad the left of the shorter number with `0` 's to match the longer number (if one input is shorter than the other).

Answer (score 0):

Cin doesn't work with arrays the way you think it does. You will need to loop over the array to fill in each element individually!

Also, C++ has the bool type, which you could use here instead of char. Cin >> bool will convert a digit entered to either false (if the digit is 0) or true. Much closer to what you need.

Regarding your addition: it makes little sense to implement "binary addition". Addition is just addition, the results are always the same, no matter in which base. So, I'd recommend converting your array of bools to an integer. And then just add integers! If you want to print them as binary, you can just iterate through there integer, using 1<<shift to shift a mask to the right position, and using the bitwise & operator to extract the bit at that position.